# Displaying commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am playing in minecraft 1.12.2

I want to make a command block that when activated runs the /seed command and tells the world seed to everyone on the server (preferably in the game chat. Is there any way to do this

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no way to do this dynamically, you can only copy the seed manually and insert it into a command.

(In 1.13+ you could run `/execute store result score @s score_name run seed` and it's probably possible to do something similar with `/stats` in 1.12, but that overflows the integer range for a scoreboard almost every time, so you don't get the correct number.
There is also no JSON component that displays the seed.)

Comment: Wouldn't ```/execute as @a run seed``` work? (in 1.13+)

Comment: No, it still just says it to yourself.